# Run all open tests in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper, testdriven.net, test-runner

Is there an easy way to run all tests in open test classes in Visual Studio. I find that this is what I most often need to do.

Mostly I use Resharpers or TestDriven.NET testrunners, and I cant find any easy way to do that in either testrunner. In Resharper it would be nice to have a "Add all open tests to session" feature, but after much googling I cant find one, or any other easy way to do this.

Is there a tool, plugin, or what-not to do this?

Comment: If you suggest this in their bugtracker (http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/), I'll vote for it. This would be pretty useful.

Comment: GOod idea, ill see what I can do.

Answer (score 11):

AFAIK, there isn't such a feature.

Alternatively you could

- run all tests **within a class** (by setting the cursor to the class, outside of a method, and pressing `Ctrl+R T`)
- run all tests **within a namespace** (by setting the cursor into the namespace, outside of a class, and pressing `Ctrl+R T`)

After you managed to run the interesting tests (however), you could

- run **these tests again** by pressing `Ctrl+R D`
- run **failed tests again** by pressing `Ctrl+R F`

Then you can create test lists. I don't do this, it's to time consuming to keep them up to date.

Comment: You can also click the three-circles icon next to the test class, and "Append to session", and only run them once you've added all the tests you want. That way you're not waiting for all the tests to run every time you add another test class to the session. But agreed, I don't know of any way to automatically build a session from all tests in currently-open files.

Comment: Yes, basically thats what I do today. At some point you have so many test classes it becomes tedious. Also, if I close my solution for the day, to reopen it the next day, all my code is opened, test classes and all, but the test session is not preserved..

Answer (score 1):

Run ALL tests: Press Ctrl + R, A

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered automating your tests to be run on a build server under something like CruiseControl?

Comment: Whether you have a continuous integration server or not, you still need to run the tests frequently as you code. CI is just a safety net -- it doesn't remove the need to run tests yourself.

Comment: Yes we run cruisecontrol.net. But ofcourse I still need to run the tests as often as possible while I work.